How do I mount an AC wall unit onto a wall insulated with EPS foam insulation
I'm looking to insulate my house using blocks of expanded polystyrene (EPS) insulation that are to be glued on the wall. However my issue is that I have a couple of AC wall units, that are currently mounted on consoles screwed into a brick wall.
My problem is that the insulation will be put on top of the bricks, and the material is very soft, so I don't think it'll be able to support the weight of the AC units, if I just reinstall the consoles on the newly insulated wall.
What's the solution here? Is there some sort of insulating insert material that's solid enough to bear the weight of the AC consoles?
My friend suggested XPS, which is a sturdier foam similar to EPS, but I fear it's still not good enough.
If someone has experience with this issue, could you please offer some advice?

Are you speaking of mini-split units or something like through the wall units?  How thick is the insulation? Can't you get longer bolts?

Foam is soft, but it still has non-zero bearing capacity. (We can easily insulate with foam board under a concrete slab on which vehicles will park, for example.) Can you help us estimate the forces involved and the area over which the force is (or could be) spread?

Yeah, mini-splits, didn't know the word, sorry. The foam is going to be 15cm thick. I can get bolts that are long enough, but I fear it's not going to be a good solution, since the bolts are going to go through the insulation, which doesn't support it at all.

What kind of foam, how thick, and is there wallboard over it to help distribute forces?
I have a lumber rack on the wall in my basement workshop, which is fully loaded and so carrying considerable weight. The wall is green board over InSoFast EPS panels (no affiliation, just a customer) over concrete. The manufacturer said that the plastic studs built into the insulation panels would probably be able to handle this load, but I chose instead to drill through the insulation and into the concrete and use Tapcon lag bolts for the best available support. The forces on the wallboard and foam are distributed enough by the rack that I could tighten this down quite firmly,
Your consoles have to be lighter.
So: if you are installing the EPS between studs, or using an EPS system with studs built in, you can simply screw into the studs. If you are using straight EPS, long fasteners into the brick should do the job for you. You might even be able to get away with wallboard anchors, assuming that you are going to cover the EPS with wallboard.
(Which you should.  Exposed EPS can be a fire hazard, and at least in my area it must be sheathed behind a barrier material such as wall board or plywood. ... Of course, if you are putting plywood over the insulation, you can just screw into that.)

So use longer bolts and then make a triangle using pins from the head of the bolt down to the wall a 45 degree angle - but you will need a long drill.
